# c# switch - case con string de varias palabras

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de realizar está validación:

```
                const string cc = "CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA";
                const string ce = "CEDULA DE EXTRANJERIA";
                const string nit = "NIT";

                var type = "Cédula de ciudadania";

                // Convertir a mayúscula sostenida y quitarle tildes.
                byte[] tempBytes;
                tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(type.ToUpper());
                string asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes);

                // asciiStr quedaría así: "CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA", después de está conversión. 
                switch (asciiStr)
                {
                    case cc:
                        tipoDocument = "Cédula de ciudadanía";
                        break;
                    case ce:
                        tipoDocument = "Cédula de extranjería";
                        break;
                    case nit:
                        tipoDocument = "NIT";
                        break;
                    default:
                        tipoDocument = "DEFAULT";
                        break;
                };
```

Pero siempre la variable tipoDocument es igual a "DEFAULT", o sea siempre el switch llega a default.

También he intentado de está manera:

```
if (asciiStr.Equals("CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    tipoDocument = "Cédula de ciudadanía";
                }
                else if (asciiStr.Equals("CEDULA DE EXTRANJERIA", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    tipoDocument = "Cédula de extranjería";
                }
                else if (asciiStr.Equals("NIT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    tipoDocument = "NIT";
                }else
                {
                    tipoDocument = "DEFAULT";
                }
```

Pero siempre termina ninguna condición se cumple y siempre termina en else.

Comment: Estas seguro que la variable `asciiStr` esta tomando el valor que esperas ? si pones un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionas la variable que valor observas

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si la variable `asciiStr ` devuelve: "CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA"

Comment: donde estas declarando la variable tipoDocument tu switch es correcto, pero tal vez la estas sobre escribiendo. Agrega todo el codigo de tu metodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo pude resolver de está manera:

Coloque las variales de está manera, suprimiendo los espacios:

```
                const string cc = "CEDULADECIUDADANIA";
                const string ce = "CEDULADEEXTRANJERIA";
                const string nit = "NIT";
```

Y el switch le agregue:

```
asciiStr.Replace(" ", "")
```

y el switch - case quedó de está manera:

```
 switch (asciiStr.Replace(" ", ""))
                {
                    case cc:
                        tipoDocument = "Cédula de ciudadanía";
                        break;
                    case ce:
                        tipoDocument = "Cédula de extranjería";
                        break;
                    case nit:
                        tipoDocument = "NIT";
                        break;
                    default:
                        tipoDocument = "TEST";
                        break;
                };
```

Answer (score 2):

intenta eliminando los espacios en blanco

ejemplo:

```
switch (asciiStr.Replace (" ", ""))
 {
    case cc.Replace (" ", ""):
      tipoDocument = "Cédula de ciudadanía";
    break;
 };
```